# How to make java genreated thumbnail sharper

Tags: java, image, thumbnails, image-resizing

I have thumbnails generated in Java, but not sharp enough, why?

Comment: How exactly did you generate those thumbnails? Can you show us your code? This is not a problem with / about Java, but rather of the algorithm that you're using.

Answer (score 4):

I'm getting excellent results with the [java-image-scaling library](http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/).

Comment: I concur. I tried all sort of examples from around the web and even imgscalr which turned out to be a piece of crap. The java-image-scaling library gives much better results than any Java image scaling solution I've seen and with so many filters to choose from. It is even in the central Maven repo.

Comment: This library really just provides so much better results than imgscalr.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly because of the kernel you've used.

A [lanczos filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_filter), for instance, gives relatively sharp results.

Answer (score 2):

I found the best results are produced with Lanczos scale for thumbnails  and unsharp mask after that. Most scale algorithms apply as a first step a low pass filter (blur) and sub-sampling after that, this makes scaled down images to look not sharp enough.